# Is it possible to have 1 pod with multiple PVC of different namespaces attached

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

**Example:**

**Namespace: a**

```
 PVC: a-pvc
 Pod: main-pod-to-work-with
```

**Mounts:**

```
a-pvc; name: a-pvc-mount; path: /pvc/a-files
b-pvc; name: b-pvc-mount; path: /pvc/b-files
c-pvc; name: c-pvc-mount; path: /pvc/c-files
```

**Namespace: b**

```
 PVC: b-pvc
```

**Namespace: c**

```
 PVC: c-pvc
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, pv and pvc are binding 1:1. I will elaborate in answer.

Comment: The PVCs have to be in the same namespace as their Pod.

Answer (score 2):

[**TL;DR**]
In the same `namespace`, one `PVC` can be re-used by two or more different `pod`s. However, it is impossible for a `pod` to mount volumes based on `PVCs` from two different `namespaces` (that would violate the main idea behind `namespace`s - isolating resources allocated to different users).

**More info**

As per [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#introduction) docs:

> A **PersistentVolume** (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator or dynamically provisioned using Storage Classes.
>
> A **PersistentVolumeClaim** (PVC) is a request for storage by a user.

Bit lower in documentation you have [Binding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#binding) part, where you can find information:

> Once bound, PersistentVolumeClaim binds are exclusive, regardless of how they were bound. A PVC to PV binding is a one-to-one mapping, using a ClaimRef which is a bi-directional binding between the PersistentVolume and the PersistentVolumeClaim.

`Pod` and `PVC` are `namespaced` resources. It mean's that if you have `pod` in `default namespace`, `pvc` also must be in the same `namespace`.

```
$ kubectl api-resources
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION                        NAMESPACED   KIND
...
persistentvolumeclaims            pvc          v1                                true         PersistentVolumeClaim
persistentvolumes                 pv           v1                                false        PersistentVolume
pods                              po           v1                                true         Pod
...
```

If you would create `pod` in `default` [namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/), it won't be albe to see resources in other `namespace`. That's why you need to specify `namespace` in some commends. If you won't specify it, your output will be from `default` namespace.

```
$ kubectl get po
No resources found in default namespace.
$ kubectl get po -n kube-system
NAME                                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
event-exporter-gke-564fb97f9-wtx9w                          2/2     Running   0          9m2s
fluentbit-gke-8tcm6                                         2/2     Running   0          8m48s
fluentbit-gke-cdm2w                                         2/2     Running   0          8m51s
```

### Test

Based on [Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) documentation you have steps to create `PV`, `PVC` and `Pods`.

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
task-pv-pod     1/1     Running   0          5m20s
task-pv-pod-2   1/1     Running   0          4m43s
task-pv-pod-3   1/1     Running   0          2m40s
```

Few pods can use the same `PVC`. But all `pods` and `PVC` are in the same `namespace`. As `pod` and `pvc` resources, it's impossible to use `pod` from one namespace to use resource from another `namespace`.

### Conclusion

Kubernetes `namespaced` resources are visible only for resources in the same `namespace` (like `pod` or `pvc`) In that situation you have specify `namespace` using `--namespace <namespace>` or `-n <namespace>`. There are also cluster-wide resources like `PersistentVolume` which don't require to specify name as they are visible in whole cluster. To get list of resources to check if it's namespaced you can use command `$ kubectl api-resources`.

If this didn't answer your question, please elaborate it.